# list sorting case insensitive using operator.attrgetter

Tags: python, list, sorting, case-insensitive

hi i have list of dictionaries .. and i want to sort it case insensitive

```
members = Person.objects.filter(person=person_id)
members_list = list(members)

members_list.sort( key = operator.attrgetter( sort_by ), reverse = False )
```

here sort_by have attribute name by whom i want to sort.
Now how can i sort with case insensitive ??

Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `sort_by` is a variable containing a string with the name of the attribute you want to use for sorting and you want to use `operator.attrgetter()`, you could use this which converts the value of the attribute it fetches to all lowercase characters for comparisons during the sort:

```
members_list.sort( key = lambda mbr: operator.attrgetter( sort_by )( mbr ).lower(),
                   reverse = False )
```

Although something like the following is easier to read as well as more efficient:

```
get_key = operator.attrgetter( sort_by )
members_list.sort( key = lambda mbr: get_key( mbr ).lower(), reverse = False )
```

Answer (score 6):

```
members_list.sort( key = lambda member: getattr(member,sort_by).lower(), reverse = False )
```

Comment: +1 *This* is a valid use case for `lambda` (ironically, you wouldn't use a lambda for this in a functional language, where you have tools like the dot `(f.g)(x) = f(g(x))`). But you need `getattr(member, sort_by)`.

Comment: sort_by is my variable which have attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question is about django. You might want to think about returning a sorted queryset instead. This means you can leave the sorting too the database and not bother with it your self. See this site: [django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: you are right but here in member_list i have some foriegn key values too, through reverse relationship. i also need those in this list. so at query i can't use order_by.

Comment: by this reason i used above method to sort the list.

Comment: It can often be cheaper to sort in python rather than the DB, especially for non-indexed columns.